# "save some cost"

Tags: word-request

When one tries to say something like *"If we can walk instead of taking a cab, that will save us some cost"*, "save some cost" doesn't sound right, does it?

Can we say "save us some money"? Alternatively, what expressions are there that include "cost"? Does "save from some cost" make sense?

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid *cost* in this context, unless you follow the guidance given by @rhealitycheck. You could also use *cost* as a verb:

> Walking would cost less than taking a cab.

But used as an object with *save*, I strongly agree with your hunch: I don't like the sound of *cost* at all.

> <strike>If we can walk instead of taking a cab, we can save some cost</strike>.
>   If we can walk instead of taking a cab, we can save some money.

We must save something quantifiable, such as money, or some other synonym:

> If we can walk instead of taking a cab, we can save some cash.

but words like *price* or *cost* do NOT describe what we are saving. The cost may be *reduced*, but that is not the same as "saving cost."

Answer (score 4):

You can say "it will cost less" i.e. use *cost* as verb rather than a noun. Or you can say "it will be less [costly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/costly)".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using some you could say, "if we walk instead of taking a cab, it would save us the cost of the cab." It's more explicit but I think it would give you what you are looking for.